# Не получается выполнить запрос CURL

Tags: php, парсер, curl, csrf, php-curl

Пишу парсер cURL, так как API нет. Суть следующая - сначала по GET ссылке генерируется токен, а затем этот токен подставляется в ссылку и приходит ответ в формате JSPN. На локальном сервере все отлично работает, но на хостинге отказывается работать. В случае, если я укажу прямую GET ссылку с токеном, то ответ приходит, иначе приходит NULL, но при этом ошибок нет и код 200. Пробовал указывать заголовки браузера - не помогло. Знаю, что тот сайт написан на Angular. Код парсера:

```
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE); 
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT   5.1; en-GB; rv:1.9.1.4) Gecko/20091016 Firefox/3.5.4');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
$page = curl_exec($curl);
echo var_dump($page);
echo curl_error($curl);
curl_close($curl);
```

Но проблема в том, что попробовал вставить строчку:

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
```

и мне выдало ошибку, что защита CSRF отклонила мой запрос, ссылаясь на отсутствие REFERER. Подставив REFERER в ответе приходила ошибка об отсутствии куки. И тут начинается самое сложное для меня - явным способом, как я прочитал на различных ресурсах, CSRF токен не указывается в мета теге. Где мне его взять  как мне дальше быть, чтобы получить полный ответ, я не знаю. Буду благодарен за любые советы!

Comment: А вы думаете для чего эти защиты придумывают?

Comment: Как правило CSRF токен лежит в форме или в мета, посмотрите сайт, csrf нужен как правило для post запросов(put/patch/delete) в зависимости от защиты всё это сможете обходить=)

Comment: Если тот сайт на ангуляре то курл может не увидеть нужных вам данных так как они рендерятся отдельно, насколько мне известно курл не может в исполнение JS

Comment: Да, в том и дело, что только при использовании POST происходит упоминание CSRF. Но в этой ситуации я не могу понять, почему на локальном сервере все работает, а на хостинге нет. Да и на хостинге, если задать прямую ссылку, то ничего не требует - ни заголовков, ни REFERER, ни куки ...

Comment: А вы локально отправляете запросы к своему серверу? Или к удалённому?

Comment: К удаленному, конечно же. Сначала идет GET запрос, потом я получаю токен этого запроса и формирую GET ссылку типа ?id=token.

Comment: Может он ждёт токен в заголовке?

Comment: Ну если и так, то я тогда представления не имею, как должна выглядеть ссылка. Эти 2 GET запроса я достал через инспектор, потому что при поиске по сайту они не отображаются в адресной строке. В инспекторе я также видел и искомый CSRF токен, но, к сожалению, не понимаю, как мне его применить в рамках моей задачи.

Comment: Что хоть за сайт и какие запросы?

Comment: Ну парсить хочу с сайта mirsud.spb.ru а запросы - сначала я из поиска получаю список нужных мне страниц и потом с каждой достаю нужную мне информацию.

Comment: Результаты запроса хотите парсить?

Comment: Для начала да. С логикой кода я разобрался, на локалке все работает - нужная информация записывается в массив без каких-либо ошибок. Кстати в текущей ситуации, когда на хостинге пытаюсь парсить и получаю пустой ответ - один раз на 1000 всё таки получил ответ в нужном мне JSON формате.

Comment: Там вроде NG стоит, может в его корнях он получает токен для CSRF

Comment: Ну я понял, что в данном случае токен как-то не дефолтно получается. Мне не понятно, почему один раз всё таки ответ пришёл. Это нормальная ситуация или всё таки означает то, что токен не требуется и проблема в другом?

Comment: Может запрос был без CSRF защиты?

Comment: Тот же самый запрос, что и сейчас. Просто при случайном обновлении страницы пришел ответ.